# Broken layout on Register Your App page - All browsers

Tags: bug, design, stackapps

The layout is broken on the [Register Your V2.0 Application](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register) page. See the image below.

[image]

I’m using Safari 9.1.1 on El Capitan (MacBook Pro 15’’). The issue is reproducible all times when I visit this page. I’m not using any kind of page scaling.

**Update:** It looks like in Chrome and IE the issue is the same so it might be reproducible on all browsers.